# Can I use inserted code with jquery for a new jquery used

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example : When click on the aaa button,  'bbb' button is inserted but later when click on the bbb button i dont have allert. Why ?

```
<button id="aaaa">aaaa</button>
<div id="abc"></div>

<script>
   $("#aaaa").click(function() {
        $("#abc").html('<button id="bbb">bbb</button>');

    });

    $("#bbb").click(function() {
        alert("sasasa");
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Come oooon, super classic question, has already been asked and answered countless times http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 2):

Basically your `$("#bbb")` returns no matches, so does not register the click event at all. That element only exists later.

As the item is added dynamically, you need to use a delegated event handler, attached to a non-changing ancestor of the element:

e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', "#bbb", function() {
    alert("sasasa");
});
```

This version of `on` applies the jQuery selector at *event time*, so the element does not need to exist until event time (rather than when the event was registered).

`document` is the default if nothing else is closer/convenient. Do not use body as it has a bug (to do with styling). In your example you probably want to attach to `'#abc'`.

e.g.

```
$('#abc').on('click', "#bbb", function() {
    alert("sasasa");
});
```

Comment: In this case he can use the first parent element that is already in the DOM: so the div containing the new button

Comment: @Lelio Faieta: Already advised and already added that in description. The speed difference is negligible anyway as it is at user-click speed.

Comment: You are right about performance. IMHO i prefer not to use document when possible for code readibility (just my own opinion anyway) :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$("#abc").on(click,'#bbb',function() {
    alert("sasasa");
});
```

cause you need to use delegated events to use jquery on elements added to a DOM